# dnn nodeselector show show siblings if no children

Tags: nodes, dotnetnuke

My curent menu template is the following :

```
<nav class="col-md-12" data-responsive-menu="true" data-responsive-levels="">
    <ul class="col-md-12" id="sublist">
        [*>NODE-TOP]
    </ul>
</nav>

[>NODE-TOP]

    [?ENABLED]
        <a href="[=URL]" id="sidemenuitem" [?TARGET]target="[=TARGET]" [/?]><li class="subitem">[=TEXT]</li></a>
    [?ELSE]
        <a href="#" id="sidemenuitem"><li class="subitem">[=TEXT]</li></a>
    [/?]

[/>]
```

This shows the children of the current page and if you click on one of the children it will show the siblings of that page.

now i would like it to show the children if it has any and otherwise it should show it's siblings.

how do i accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer with the help of : 
http://demo.40fingers.net/dnn-ddr-demo-skin/

i added the following xslt script for it to work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:param name="ControlID" />
<xsl:param name="Options" />
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="root" />
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="root">
<nav class="col-md-12" data-responsive-menu="true" data-responsive-levels="">
    <ul class="Root" id="sublist">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="0"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="NoChildren">
                <xsl:call-template name="NoChildren"/>
            </xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
</nav>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node">

        <xsl:param name="level" />
        <xsl:param name="NoChildren" />

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$NoChildren='true'">
                    <!-- Render Siblings as Active page does not have Children-->
                <a id="sidemenuitem" href="{@url}">
                <xsl:choose>

                    <xsl:when test="@breadcrumb = 1 and @selected = 1">
                        <li class="subitem active">
                            <span>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <li class="subitem">
                            <span>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                            </span>
                        </li>
                    </xsl:otherwise>

                </xsl:choose>

                </a>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- Render Children of Active page-->
                    <xsl:if test="@breadcrumb=1">
                        <xsl:for-each select="node">
                            <a id="sidemenuitem" href="{@url}">
                                <xsl:choose>

                                    <xsl:when test="@breadcrumb = 1 and @selected = 1">
                                        <li class="subitem active">
                                            <span>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <li class="subitem">
                                            <span>
                                                <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>

                                </xsl:choose>
                            </a>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:if >
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>




<xsl:template name="NoChildren">
    <!-- If the Active page has no children -->
    <xsl:for-each select='/Root/root/node'>
        <xsl:if test="@selected=1">
            <xsl:if test="not(node)">
                <xsl:text>true</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean. But I use the code below to generate the menu tree with submenus.

```
<nav class="menuBalk">
    [*>NODE-TOP]
</nav>

[>NODE-TOP]
    <div class="topMenu[?FIRST] first[/?][?LAST] last[/?][?SELECTED] active[/?]">
        [?ENABLED]
            <a href="[=URL]" [?TARGET]target="[=TARGET]" [/?]>[=TEXT]</a>
        [?ELSE]
            <a href="#">[=TEXT]</a>
        [/?]
        [?NODE]
            <span class="subMenuBalk">
                [*>NODE]
            </span>
        [/?]
    </div>
[/>]

[>NODE]
    <div class="subMenu[?FIRST] first[/?][?LAST] last[/?][?SELECTED] active[/?]">
        [?ENABLED]
            <a href="[=URL]" [?TARGET]target="[=TARGET]" [/?]>[=TEXT]</a>
        [?ELSE]
            <a href="#">[=TEXT]</a>
        [/?]
        [?NODE]
            <ul class="subSubMenuBalk">
                [*>NODE]
            </ul>
        [/?]
    </div>
[/>]
```

Comment: This shows the siblings AND the children. I need it to show the children if it has any and if it does not have any children it should show it's siblings.

Comment: I doubt that what you want is possible. In your situation if a root page has children and one of those children does not have any children of its own, it will create an infinite menu structure.